# Powershell - Get users by group

Tags: powershell, user

I had a script who get all users of sharepoint site. So I can get group for each member but can you get all group of sharepoint site and get all users of each group?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following PowerShell script for getting all users for each SP group for given SPWeb

```
  $web = Get-SPWeb "http://YourWebURL/"
  foreach ($group in $web.groups){
write-host -foregroundcolor white "----Collecting users from group:"$group.Name "..."
foreach($user in $group.users) {
  if ($user.Loginname.StartsWith("SHAREPOINT\")) {continue}
  if ($user.Loginname.StartsWith("NT")) {continue}


  write-host -foregroundcolor Yellow "-------User:"$user.DisplayName
}
  }
  $web.Dispose()
```